# Get URL & Query from WebView's onNavigationStateChange event

Tags: javascript, android, node.js, react-native, webview

Currently I am able to get the base URL of a page when clicked using the following WebView configuration

```js
const handleUrlChange = (url:string) => {
   if (url == videUrl) return;

   setVideoUrl(url);
   console.log(url);
}; 

<WebView 
   startInLoadingState={true} 
   source={{ uri: 'https://m.youtube.com/'}} 
   onError={err => console.warn(err)}
   originWhitelist={['https://m.youtube.com/']}
   onNavigationStateChange={({ url }) => {
      urlChangeHandler(url)
   }}
/>
```

The problem is, the *entire* URL does not show.

When going to `https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=aqz-KE-bpKQ` only `https://m.youtube.com/` returns as `url`. I need to be able to read `watch?v=aqz-KE-bpKQ` as well to identify which video a user has navigated to.

How can I retrieve the entire URL?